# IIS 10 - File or directory not found

Tags: .net, iis, server, http-status-code-404

I have a web app made in Visual Studio.
Whenever I navigate to it, I get a 404.
I can access for example this: "xyz.net/res/image.png", however I cannot "default.aspx".

Default Document:
[image: Default Document]

Binding:
[image: Binding]

App Pool:
[image: App Pool]

This happens when I navigate to localhost on port 80:
[image: This happens when I navigate to localhost on port 80.]

I have set up and ran a web server before with IIS, but since then I reinstalled Windows and I can't figure it out.
Before I tinkered with it, I could access localhost.
The file paths seem correct, though I don't think I would be able to access the png files otherwise.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anyone else struggling with this issue. The fix was to enable Application Development under the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" under the Windows Control Panel.

```
Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn 
Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe 
command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
```

[image: Turn on ASP.NET]

I attached a screenshot of where to find the ASP.NET features under Web Server IIS > Application development.

Hope this helps anyone who is getting that 404 error messaging trying to get an .aspx page to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it! I enabled some Windows features, and that's it.
I cannot tell which one helped, because I enabled dozens of them, but if you face this problem and cannot fix it, you could give it a go.